# How to change comma to pipe and remove duplicates and trim last delimiter in LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle12.1

I have a query which result is: *(EDIT: 13.06.2023 12:30)*

```
|ID|USER_NAME           |
|--|--------------------|
|1 |A1,A1,A1,B12,B12,C32|
|2 |A1                  |
|3 |B12,C32             |
```

**Query for the above result:**

```
SELECT 
ID,
LISTAGG (user_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_name )
From my_table
GROUP BY ID;
```

**What I have tried to replace ',' with '|' and remove the duplicates and trim the last delimiter is:**

```
SELECT
ID,
RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(LISTAGG (user_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_name ), '([^,]+)(,|\1)+', '\1|'),'|') 
From my_table 
GROUP BY ID;
```

**The output is:**

```
|ID|USER_NAME   |
|--|------------|
|1 |A1|2|B12|C32|
|2 |A1          |
|3 |B12|C32     |
```

**EDIT:**
*The LISTAGG and REGEXP should be part of a longer query and not be a standalone SELECT (output of LISTAGG should be a column of a long query). The example should only show what output I want to have in the end.*

The second value for user_name and ID 1 is not correct.
How can I get the correct values? What is wrong in the query?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First select distinct values, and then apply `listagg` to already distinct data set:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT DISTINCT id, user_name
         FROM my_table)
  SELECT id, 
         LISTAGG (user_name, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY user_name)
    FROM temp
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Already tried that. It is very good but the LISTAGG should be part of a long query and can not be a sepaerate SELECT. Sorry forgot to add this to the question. Edit it now.

Comment: In that case, do similarly to what I did - create a CTE (or a subquery) which will return aggregates usernames, and then join it (the CTE or subquery) to the rest of your tables (probably on the ID column).

Comment: ok try it but is there no "easier" way then a subquery?

Comment: It would be, if you're on (at least) Oracle 19c whose LISTAGG supports DISTINCT, so you'd simply `LISTAGG(DISTINCT user_name, '|') ...`

Comment: yes I know that for 19c it is easy ^^. For other columns I found a way to do it but this one I'm struggling..

Answer (score 0):

You may use `collect` aggregation to get distinct values and then use `listagg` over collection.

```
create table sample_table (id int, user_name varchar2(10))
```

```
begin
  insert into sample_table values(1, 'A1');
  insert into sample_table values(1, 'A1');
  insert into sample_table values(1, 'A1');
  insert into sample_table values(1, 'B12');
  insert into sample_table values(1, 'B12');
  insert into sample_table values(1, 'C32');
  insert into sample_table values(2, 'A1');
  insert into sample_table values(3, 'B12');
  insert into sample_table values(3, 'C32');
  insert into sample_table values(3, 'B12');
  commit;
end;/
```

```
with grouped as (
  select
    id,
    cast(collect(distinct user_name) as sys.odcivarchar2list) as qwe
  from sample_table
  group by id
)
select
  id,
  (
    select
      listagg(column_value, '|') within group(order by column_value) as user_name
    from table(grouped.qwe)
  ) as user_name
from grouped
```

| ID | USER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1|B12|C32 |
| 2 | A1 |
| 3 | B12|C32 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b-BRd_QD)